# Как правильно создавать интерфейсы в Android MVP?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, mvp

Суть в том, что я прочитал достаточно статей на хабре про MVP, а так же изучил StackOverFlow и в принципе мне сам паттерн этот понятен. Понятная архитектура и необходимость DI, но вот чего я действительно не могу понять - по какому правилу/принципу необходимо создавать интерфейсы для Model/View/Presenter? Какие именно методы включать в интерфейс: наиболее существенные, которые отвечают за главные задачи или все? И подобное про составление интерфейсов. Может я мало искал, но статьи с примерами показывают простые примеры, где число методов в интерфейсе соответствует числу методов в модели, например. Очень хотелось бы понять именно реализацию интерфейсов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще в Presenter выноситься логика работы с сервером и бд,

поэтому в интерфейс выноситься логика типа ( "сделай запрос туда-то и верни результат (асинхронно)"), a view лишь реагирует какими-то изменениями в разметке, либо какую-то еще логику делает.

Так что в интерфейсе(для view) будут присутствовать методы типа ("покажи лодер", "покажи ошибку", и т.д.)

Comment: Т.е. необходимо для всех Presenter построить один интерфейс? Или число интерфейсов может быть разным, например, в зависимости от структуры разных Presenter?

Comment: @Gadman Из моего опыта, Вам точно нужно будет следить за жизненным циклом активити или фрагмента или вью. Так что - да, вам придется сделать базовый интерфейс который будет содержать в себе по-крайне мере методы жизненного цикла, а какие интерфейсы вы будете описывать для разных вью и презентеров, уже на Вашу фантазию.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Теперь я разобрался